# Is there a threshold for calling an interaction nonbonding on an OPDOS (overlap population density-of-states) plot?

Tags: density-functional-theory, density-of-states

I am analyzing the bonding interactions within the [XeF5]- anion (B3YLP/def2-TZVP), and I am using an OPDOS (overlap population density-of-states) plot to formalize the degree of bonding/antibonding interactions within the molecular orbitals. I would like to categorize the molecular orbitals as bonding/nonbonding/antibonding.

Bonding interactions are OPDOS > 0, antibonding is OPDOS < 0, and true nonbonding is OPDOS = 0, however it is common for literature to say an orbital is "slightly bonding" or "mostly nonbonding".

Is there a threshold that is commonly used in literature (arbitrary or not) for the characterization of the degree nonbonding (i.e. anything within OPDOS = ±0.01 is called nonbonding)? I have searched the literature with no avail.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!